# can i replace windows with ubuntu and still get the same gaming experience? Steam and Origin

Tags: games, steam

I want to switch to UBUNTU having first learned on the APPLE II with BASIC and being a Web Designer transitioning to Developer I want a shell based system geared for programming BUT, I STILL WANT TO GAME with Steam and Origin mostly is it possible? or will I not get all the games and same high graphical content of the 3D environment???

Comment: Some Steam games are available on Linux; best to check ypur library of games. It is also possible (with some hoop-jumping) to run many Windows gamex with Wine. The last fallback is to dual-boot or run virtual Windows. So it is unlikely you will get all the games, at least not without a significant effort.

Comment: I will make the effort if it is possible to completely be free from windows and not have to dual-boot as I am now I would like to free up disk space that is being used by windows but have some $ invested in gaming I don't want to lose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no guarantee that you will be able to get the same exact gaming experience.  Many games aren't available for Linux natively, and some are not capable of being run (even through PlayOnLinux or Wine-driven Steam) without a performance hit.

So, no, there's no guarantee you will be able to switch over directly and have the same exact experience.

Comment: ok thank you I guess I will have to spend my efforts trying to minimize my windows install and storage as to setup strictly for gaming thank you for quick response

Comment: sorry I'm a noob do I have to close the ? or is that up to the Moderator?

Comment: @RobrtPociecha, you can vote or select his answer as "best answer".

Comment: You can also run Windows games in a VM. With latest hardware and at least with qemu, it's possible to do PCI passthrough as well, to give direct hardware access to Windows games/drivers. You may still have problems of course, but it should be pretty reasonable to do.